Is there a faster way to move an image from matplotlib to tKinter than saving to my disk?
I’m writing a python script that constantly updates a plot and displays it in real time to the user via tKinter. Currently, I’m plotting, using plt.savefig(), then immediately using PIL to put it into a tkinter label.
This process takes about 350ms, and I’m shooting for less than 100ms.

You should show the code you are using; that will help providing a clear answer.

You can probably write the image to a BytesIO object, and (with or without Pillow) put that into a TKinter label.

Or find a way to embed Matplotlib directly into TKinter

You can save the plot to an in-memory buffer via io's BytesIO, then load the image into PIL
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# make a plot
plt.figure()
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.title("my_plot")

# make a buffer and save the plot to the buffer
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format="png")
buf.seek(0)

# open the image from the buffer and load into PIL
im = Image.open(buf)
root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(im))
label.pack()
root.mainloop()

# close the buffer
buf.close()


Well done, you did the work so go on and show us how it looks! Add a screengrab of your app and share it.
